# Amending a struct value in a dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

I've created a dictionary that takes the values of my struct and stores them. Filling this out looks as follows:

```
_screenEntry.type = typeof(string);
_screenEntry.value = tagTextBox.Text;
_screen.nodeDictionary.Add("Tag ", _screenEntry);
```

My struct looks like this for reference:

```
public struct Entry
{
    public Object value;
    public Type type;
}
```

How ever, I am now trying to amend that value that I first store. I've simply tried re-calling nodeDictionary.Add again hoping it would over write my previous entry. However, I get an error saying my dictionary already has a key called "Tag " which is self explanatory.

A quick google search lead me to find that if I wish to overwrite my initial value I simply need to call this line:

```
_screenTag = tagTextBox.Text;    
_screen.nodeDictionary["Tag "] = _screenTag;
```

But I get the following error:

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'InMoTool.Entry'

I don't really know how to convert this. Could someone possibly point to the way?

Comment: `_screen.nodeDictionary["Tag "].value = _screenTag;`? Or create a new `Entry` and overwrite the value in your dictionary entirely.

Answer (score 5):

With this code

```
_screenTag = tagTextBox.Text; // <-- is a string   
_screen.nodeDictionary["Tag "] = _screenTag;
```

You are trying to assign a `string` to an `Entry`. That's impossible.

I think that what you need is something like this:

```
 _screenTag = tagTextBox.Text;    
 _screen.nodeDictionary["Tag "] = new Entry {
                                        type=_screenTag.GetType(), 
                                        value=_screenTag
                                      };
```